# With RSYNC, how do includes and excludes combine?

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync everything in /Volumes/B/, except for Cache directories, which I want to exclude globally. Also, I don't want to rsync any other /Volume/

I have the following exclusion file:

```
+ /Volumes/B/***
- Cache/
- /Volumes/*
```

The first and 3rd line seem to work correctly, except that rsync also picks up all Cache dirs under /Volumes/B/... ( `/Volumes/B/***/Cache/` )

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

rsync reads the exclude file top down when traversing the directories.
When it visited the Caches dirs, rsync acted on the first matching pattern.
The first matching pattern was "+ /Volumes/B/***", so Cache was included.

The rule is:
When having particular subdirectories, put them first.

[Here](http://www.hyperorg.com/blogger/2008/05/10/beginner-to-beginner-rsync-exclude-from/) 's a simple step by step explanation.