# Rsync -- exclude a directory but include specific subdirectories within that directory

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, freebsd

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8270519/rsync-exclude-a-directory-but-include-a-subdirectory) but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

I want to exclude /jails folder but include /jails/web/usr/local/www. (and all other folders in the root directory).

```
--include=jails/web/usr/local/www --exclude='jails/'
```

but it's not working. it completely excludes the jails folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't the thread you mention recommend adding a trailing '/' to the end of the `--include=...` ?  The example you have in your question lacks the trailing '/'.

Comment: Even with a trailing / it doesn't work. I tried first with a trailing / but it didn't work, so I removed it to see if it would work without it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I managed to fix it by adding a trailing slash to the `include` and a trailing asterisk to the `exclude`, like so:

`--include="jails/web/usr/local/www/" --exclude="jails/*"`

Also apparently the order of the arguments matter, since putting `--exclude` first did not seem to work.